# Is there a local host version of Firebase, Like XAMPP for MySQL?

Tags: firebase, localhost, firebase-realtime-database

I need to continue working when away from the internet. Please advice on Firebase Local Server.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this command in your hosting directory:

`firebase serve`

This command will host your site to localhost:5000.

Comment: That's work for Firebase Hosting, but unfortunately not for the Firebase Database (which the question is tagged with).